# Run CSS Keyframe Animation when in Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a website, and I have some keyframe animations to fade my texts. However, the animation runs altogether at the start of the website. What I want to do is to only run the animation when the content is in the viewport. Is it possible to do this only in CSS and HTML? Or if I need javascript, how?

This is what I have so far:

My HTML

```
<div class="section_container">
  <div style="background-color:red" class="section">
    <h1 class="animate_fadeup">Page1</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:green" class="section">
    <h1 class="animate_fadeup">Page2</h1>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:blue" class="section">
    <h1 class="animate_fadeup">Page3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.section_container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  &.proximity {
    scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
  }
}
.section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: rgba(white, .5);
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: start;
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes fadeup {
  0% {
    bottom: -50px;
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.animate_fadeup {
  animation-name: fadeup;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  position: relative;
}
```

Or see my codepen:
https://codepen.io/steven97102/pen/poodwYR

Comment: Check this library [AOS](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

Comment: You can also check https://scrollmagic.io/ Library. Or use a custom javascript function to know if the element in the viewport or not.